# Display widget from post on front page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

In each of my posts I place a shop the post widget in them.  The shop the post widget plugin php is provided down below.  With this plugin you then only have to place a short short code in your post html. (the shop widget site gives you this code after you generate the widget)

An example short code you would place into post html - [show_shopthepost_widget id="2371382"]

What the widget would look like -

[image]

What I want to happen is to have the shop the post widget appear on my front page under the post title and excerpt. I tried to do this by adding in echo do_shortcode(). But that did not work.  Does anyone have any solutions? I'm stumped, and would appreciate any help.

*I will have a different widget ID for each post, since each post will have a different shop the post widget.

so my front page post preview would look like this -
[image]

here is the plugin code (the site I use for the widget has many other shopping widgets such as boutique and lookbook, which is why you'll see a few other widgets besides the shop the post widget, which is what I'm working with)

```html
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: rewardStyle Widget
Plugin URI: http://www.rewardstyle.com
Description: The rewardStyle plugin allows bloggers to use rewardStyle widgets on their WordPress blog
Author: rewardStyle
Author URI: http://www.rewardstyle.com
Version: 1.53
*/

require 'plugin-updates/plugin-update-checker.php';
$ExampleUpdateChecker = new PluginUpdateChecker_1_5(
    'http://www.rewardstyle.com/assets/info.json',
    __FILE__,
    'rewardstyle-widgets',
    1
);

/**
 * Add these to the KSES 'Allowed Post Tags' global
 * var. Keeps these tags from being removed in the
 * save/update process.
 */
$GLOBALS['allowedposttags']['iframe'] = array(
    'id'           => TRUE,
    'class'        => TRUE,
    'title'        => TRUE,
    'style'        => TRUE,
    'align'        => TRUE,
    'frameborder'  => TRUE,
    'height'       => TRUE,
    'longdesc'     => TRUE,
    'marginheight' => TRUE,
    'marginwidth'  => TRUE,
    'name'         => TRUE,
    'scrolling'    => TRUE,
    'src'          => TRUE,
    'width'        => TRUE
);
$GLOBALS['allowedposttags']['script'] = array(
    'id'    => TRUE,
    'class' => TRUE,
    'src'   => TRUE,
    'type'  => TRUE,
    'name'  => TRUE
);

/**
 * Add these to the Tiny MCE whitelist of acceptable Tags.
 * This keeps the values available when loading the page,
 * and when switching from Visual/Text Tabs
 */
function unfilter_iframe($initArray) {
  if (isset($initArray['extended_valid_elements'])) {
    $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] .= ",+iframe[id|class|title|style|align|frameborder|height|longdesc|marginheight|marginwidth|name|scrolling|src|width]";
  }
  else {
    $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = "+iframe[id|class|title|style|align|frameborder|height|longdesc|marginheight|marginwidth|name|scrolling|src|width]";
  }
  return $initArray;
}
function unfilter_script($initArray) {
  if (isset($initArray['extended_valid_elements'])) {
    $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] .= ",+script[id|class|src|type|name]";
  }
  else {
    $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = "+script[id|class|src|type|name]";
  }
  return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'unfilter_iframe');
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'unfilter_script');

// Add shortcode support to completely bypass the iframe filter
add_shortcode( 'show_rs_widget', 'rs_show_widget');
function rs_show_widget($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'wid' => '',
        'blog' => '',
        'product_ids' => '',
        'rows' => '',
        'cols' => '',
        'brand' => '',
        'price' => '',
        'hover' => ''
    ), $atts));

$h = $rows * 120;
$w = ($cols * 110) + 50;

$magic_num = 0;
$how_tall = '120';
$prod_box = 'show';
if ($brand == 1) {
    $magic_num++;
}
if ($price == 1) {
    $magic_num++;
}
if ($hover == 1) {
    $magic_num = 0;
    $prod_box = 'hover-info';
}
if ($magic_num == 1) {
    $how_tall = '162';
} else if ($magic_num == 2) {
    $how_tall = '195';
}

$out = "<div style='width: ".$w."px; height: ".$how_tall."px; margin: 0px auto; background:white;'>
           <iframe frameborder='0' width='".$w."px' height='".$how_tall."px' scrolling='no' src='http://currentlyobsessed.me/api/v1/get_widget?wid=".$wid."&blog=".$blog."&product_ids=".$product_ids."&rows=".$rows."&cols=".$cols."&brand=".$brand."&price=".$price."&hover=".$hover."'></iframe>
        </div>";

return $out;
}

function ms_show_widget($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id'       => '0',
        'image_id' => '0',
        'width'    => '0',
        'height'   => '0',
        'adblock'  => 'Disable your ad blocking software to view this content.',
        'enableJs' => 'JavaScript is currently disabled in this browser.  Reactivate it to view this content.'
    ), $atts));

    $out = '<div class="moneyspot-widget" data-widget-id="'.$id.'">
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    !function(d,s,id){
                        var e, p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? \'http\' : \'https\';
                        if(!d.getElementById(id)) {
                            e     = d.createElement(s);
                            e.id  = id;
                            e.src = p + \'://widgets.rewardstyle.com/js/widget.js\';
                            d.body.appendChild(e);
                        }
                        if(typeof(window.__moneyspot) === \'object\') {
                            if(document.readyState === \'complete\') {
                                window.__moneyspot.init();
                            }
                        }
                    }(document, \'script\', \'moneyspot-script\');
                </script>
                <div class="rs-adblock">
                    <img src="//images.rewardstyle.com/img?v=2.11&ms='.$id.'&aspect" onerror="this.parentNode.innerHTML=\'Turn off your ad blocker to view content\'" />
                    <noscript>'.$enableJs.'</noscript>
                </div>
            </div>';

    return $out;
}
add_shortcode('show_ms_widget', 'ms_show_widget');

function ltk_show_widget($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'user_id'    => '0',
        'rows'       => '1',
        'cols'       => '6',
        'show_frame' => 'true',
        'padding'    => '0'
    ), $atts));

    $out = '<div class="ltkwidget-widget" data-rows="'.$rows.'" data-cols="'.$cols.'" data-show-frame="'.$show_frame.'" data-user-id="'.$user_id.'" data-padding="'.$padding.'">
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    !function(d,s,id){
                        var e, p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? \'http\' : \'https\';
                        if(!d.getElementById(id)) {
                            e     = d.createElement(s);
                            e.id  = id;
                            e.src = p + \'://widgets.rewardstyle.com/js/ltkwidget.js\';
                            d.body.appendChild(e);
                        }
                    }(document, \'script\', \'ltkwidget-script\');
                    if(typeof(window.__ltkwidget) === \'object\'){
                        if (document.readyState === \'complete\') {
                            __ltkwidget.init();
                        }
                    }
                </script>
                <div class="rs-adblock">
                    <img src="//assets.rewardstyle.com/images/search/350.gif" onerror="this.parentNode.innerHTML=\''.$adblock.'\'" />
                    <noscript>'.$enableJs.'</noscript>
                </div>
            </div>';
    return $out;
}
add_shortcode('show_ltk_widget', 'ltk_show_widget');

function ltk_widget_version_two($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'app_id'     => '0',
        'user_id'    => '0',
        'rows'       => '1',
        'cols'       => '6',
        'show_frame' => 'true',
        'padding'    => '0'
    ), $atts));
    $out = '<div id="ltkwidget-version-two'.$app_id.'" data-appid="'.$app_id.'" class="ltkwidget-version-two">
                <script>var rsLTKLoadApp="0",rsLTKPassedAppID="'.$app_id.'";</script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="//widgets-static.rewardstyle.com/widgets2_0/client/pub/ltkwidget/ltkwidget.js"></script>
                <div widget-dashboard-settings="" data-appid="'.$app_id.'" data-userid="'.$user_id.'" data-rows="'.$rows.'" data-cols="'.$cols.'" data-showframe="'.$show_frame.'" data-padding="'.$padding.'">
                    <div class="rs-ltkwidget-container">
                        <div ui-view=""></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
    return $out;
}
add_shortcode('show_ltk_widget_version_two', 'ltk_widget_version_two');

function lookbook_show_widget($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id'    => '0',
        'adblock'  => 'Turn off your ad blocker to view content',
        'enableJs' => 'Turn on your JavaScript to view content'
    ), $atts));

    $out = '<div class="lookbook-widget" data-widget-id="'.$id.'">
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    !function(d,s,id){
                        var e, p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? \'http\' : \'https\';
                        if(!d.getElementById(id)) {
                            e     = d.createElement(s);
                            e.id  = id;
                            e.src = p + \'://widgets.rewardstyle.com/js/lookbook.js\';
                            d.body.appendChild(e);
                        }
                        if(typeof(window.__lookbook) === \'object\') if(d.readyState === \'complete\') {
                            window.__lookbook.init();
                        }
                    }(document, \'script\', \'lookbook-script\');
                </script>
                <div class="rs-adblock">
                    <img src="//assets.rewardstyle.com/images/search/350.gif" style="width:15px;height:15px;" onerror="this.parentNode.innerHTML=\''.$adblock.'\'" />
                    <noscript>'.$enableJs.'</noscript>
                </div>
            </div>';
    return $out;
}
add_shortcode('show_lookbook_widget', 'lookbook_show_widget');

function shopthepost_show_widget($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id'    => '0',
        'adblock'  => 'Turn off your ad blocker to view content',
        'enableJs' => 'Turn on your JavaScript to view content'
    ), $atts));

    $out = '<div class="shopthepost-widget" data-widget-id="'.$id.'">
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    !function(d,s,id){
                        var e, p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? \'http\' : \'https\';
                        if(!d.getElementById(id)) {
                            e     = d.createElement(s);
                            e.id  = id;
                            e.src = p + \'://widgets.rewardstyle.com/js/shopthepost.js\';
                            d.body.appendChild(e);
                        }
                        if(typeof window.__stp === \'object\') if(d.readyState === \'complete\') {
                            window.__stp.init();
                        }
                    }(document, \'script\', \'shopthepost-script\');
                </script>
                <div class="rs-adblock">
                    <img src="//assets.rewardstyle.com/images/search/350.gif" style="width:15px;height:15px;" onerror="this.parentNode.innerHTML=\''.$adblock.'\'" />
                    <noscript>'.$enableJs.'</noscript>
                </div>
            </div>';
    return $out;
}
add_shortcode('show_shopthepost_widget', 'shopthepost_show_widget');

function boutique_show_widget($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id'    => '0',
        'adblock'  => 'Turn off your ad blocker to view content',
        'enableJs' => 'Turn on your JavaScript to view content'
    ), $atts));

    $out = '<div class="boutique-widget" data-widget-id="'.$id.'">
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    !function(d,s,id){
                        var e, p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? \'http\' : \'https\';
                        if(!d.getElementById(id)) {
                            e     = d.createElement(s);
                            e.id  = id;
                            e.src = p + \'://widgets.rewardstyle.com/js/boutique.js\';
                            d.body.appendChild(e);
                        }
                        if(typeof window.__boutique === \'object\') if(d.readyState === \'complete\') {
                            window.__boutique.init();
                        }
                    }(document, \'script\', \'boutique-script\');
                </script>
                <div class="rs-adblock">
                    <img src="//assets.rewardstyle.com/images/search/350.gif" style="width:15px;height:15px;" onerror="this.parentNode.innerHTML=\''.$adblock.'\'" />
                    <noscript>'.$enableJs.'</noscript>
                </div>
            </div>';
    return $out;
}
add_shortcode('show_boutique_widget', 'boutique_show_widget');

add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');

?>
```

and then my front-page.php

```html
<?php
/*
 * Template Name:
 */

get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel');

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1)
] );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div id="ajax">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();

        if ( $i % 7 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
        <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>>
            <div class="large-front-container">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                </div>
            <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <div class="front-post-info">
            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php get_template_part ('front-page-shop'); ?>
                                 <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                <?php echo do_shortcode("show_shopthepost_widget"); ?>
            </article><?php

        } else { // Small posts ?>
            <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-4' ); ?>>
                <div class="front-thumbnail-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?></div>
                <a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php get_template_part ('front-page-shop'); ?>
                                 <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
             <?php echo do_shortcode("show_shopthepost_widget"); ?>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        $i++;
    }?>
    </div>
    <?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
       load_more_button();
    }
}
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
get_footer();
```

updated front-page.php

```html
<?php
/*
 * Template Name:
 */

get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel');

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1)
] );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div id="ajax">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();

        if ( $i % 7 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
        <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>>
            <div class="large-front-container">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?>
                </div>
            <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <div class="front-post-info">
            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php get_template_part ('front-page-shop'); ?>
                                 <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
                <?php echo do_shortcode("show_shopthepost_widget"); ?>
                <?php if (shortcode_exists('show_shopthepost_widget')) {

    // Get the value of the custom field defined in the editor
    $widgetId = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'shortcode_id', true);

    // Check if a value is set
    if (!empty($widgetId)) {

        $shortcode = '[show_shopthepost_widget id="'.$widgetId.'"]';

    } else {

        // or use a default widget
        $shortcode = '[show_shopthepost_widget id="12345_some_id"]';
    }

    do_shortcode($shortcode);
} ?>
            </article><?php

        } else { // Small posts ?>
            <article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-4' ); ?>>
                <div class="front-thumbnail-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?></div>
                <a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php get_template_part ('front-page-shop'); ?>
                                 <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div>
             <?php if (shortcode_exists('show_shopthepost_widget')) {

    // Get the value of the custom field defined in the editor
    $widgetId = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'shortcode_id', true);

    // Check if a value is set
    if (!empty($widgetId)) {

        $shortcode = '[show_shopthepost_widget id="'.$widgetId.'"]';

    } else {

        // or use a default widget
        $shortcode = '[show_shopthepost_widget id="12345_some_id"]';
    }

    do_shortcode($shortcode);
} ?>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        $i++;
    }?>
    </div>
    <?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
       load_more_button();
    }
}
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, [do_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) is exactly what you need, except you need to input the entire shortcode as is, without altering it (ie removing the `[]`)

This should display the widget above just fine:

```
echo do_shortcode('[show_shopthepost_widget id="2371382"]');
```

Also, I would suggest wrapping it in a [shortcode_exists()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_exists) check, otherwise it will spit out the shortcode on the page if the plugin is disabled or unavailable for any reason. *Note that this function requires the shortcode to be passed without the `[]`.*

```
if (shortcode_exists('show_shopthepost_widget')) {

    echo do_shortcode('[show_shopthepost_widget id="2371382"]');
}
```

The [Wordpress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site might have more answers for you if you're ever stuck with WP. Hope this helps!

*edit*

### Dynamic solution

If you need to display a different shortcode on each page, you can modify the above code to use custom fields to display any widget you associate with a page, or display a default widget if you didn't set any.

#### In the content editor

To do so, you need to edit your pages in your site's `wp-admin` and [add a custom field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to them with the ID of the widget you want to appear on the page, and name it something sensible like `shortcode_id`.

#### In your theme

You need to modify the logic to get the post meta with the `shortcode_id` key associated with your current page, and create the shortcode to display accordingly. Also, you can set a default widget that will appear if you don't set any for a page.

```
if (shortcode_exists('show_shopthepost_widget')) {

    // Get the value of the custom field defined in the editor
    $widgetId = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'shortcode_id', true);

    // Check if a value is set
    if (!empty($widgetId)) {

        $shortcode = '[show_shopthepost_widget id="'.$widgetId.'"]';

    } else {

        // or use a default widget
        $shortcode = '[show_shopthepost_widget id="12345_some_id"]';
    }

    echo do_shortcode($shortcode);
}
```

Comment: This worked to show that specific shop the post widget under each post. However each post has a different shop the post widget.  So the id will be different for each widget.

Comment: Oh in that case you need to associate each page with its widget ID somehow. Have you tried looking into custom fields? I'll update my answer.

Comment: So would I paste this code into my front-page.php, and if so how would I correctly add the code in? or do I put it in my functions.php

Comment: You need to replace the '<?php echo do_shortcode("show_shopthepost_widget"); ?>' line in your original code with this block. Then simply add the widget IDs as custom fields to your pages via the post editor, and it should work as expected.

Comment: Ok so I added in the new updated front-page.php. Does that look correct?  How do I add the widget IDs as a custom field?

Comment: Yes, but delete the previous do_shortcode line. Also, it should be "echo do_shortcode" but I missed that when writing the example, editing my answer now.
You can [read up on adding custom fields in the WP codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Usage) in a flash, the docs are straightforward.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134424/discussion-between-ppajer-and-user6738171).

Answer (score 0):

A `do_shortcode` must be similar to

`<?php do_shortcode("[show_shopthepost_widget]"); ?>` - your code doesn't have `[]`